# Accessing hubs - Angularjs, asp.net mvc and SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am new in using `SignalR` and I find it hard to setup in my application.

**App.js**

I got code here in my app.run(); that checks whether a user was already logged in.

```
LoginUserService.isLogged().then(function(msg){
   if (msg.data["authenticated"]) {
      var id = $cookies.get('UserId');

      var TestHub= $.connection.testHub;

        $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function () {
            //I get the id of online user and pass it on makeOnline method in my testHub
            TestHub.server.makeOnline(id);
        });
   }
});
```

**controller.js**

Here in my controller I made connection to the same hub in my `app.js` in order for me to get the online clients. This controller can be accessed by admin only

```
app.controller('Users',function($scope){
    var hub = $.connection.testHub;
    hub.client.allOnline = function (users) {
        console.log("client.allonline(" + JSON.stringify(users) + ")");
    }
    $.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function () {
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

**TestHub.cs**

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> _locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();
private static object _lock = new object();

public void MakeOnline(int userid)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                foreach (int id in _locks.Values)
                {
                    if (userid == id)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                _locks.AddOrUpdate(Context.ConnectionId, userid, (key, oldValue) => userid);
                Clients.All.allOnline(_locks.Values);
            }
        }
```

My codes in `app.js` works but whenever I go to `Users` controller I can't get any result in `hub.client.allOnline`. I tried refreshing the browser and that's the only time I got result. Any ideas what should I do?

Comment: If you `return ;` when your userId matches one in your dictionary, your `Clients.All.allOnline(_locks.Values);` function won't be executed. Also you are using a ConcurrentDictionary so there is no need to use a lock too.

Comment: I need the lock sir for checking if that user already exist or not in my ConcurrentDictionary. If I remove it I got no userId. It is working fine when I refresh the browser. After I refresh it, I tried logging in to another browser with my test user and `Clients.All.allOnline(_locks.Values)` updated automatically. But my problem is I don't want to refresh the browser in order for the my controller to fetch the data in my ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: I got it now. In order for me to got the changes I have to invoke `$.connection.hub.stop();` first in my controller then start the connection again

Comment: Now I don't why my Ondisconnected event in SignalR Hub won't fire whenever a client close their browser but the other event like OnConnected and OnReconnected are firing